# problems to run sdl2 under python 3.6.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Learning kivy. The script:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button()

Test().run()
```

The error:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Paulo\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-02-16_2.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\Paulo\PycharmProjects\kivy\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\Paulo\PycharmProjects\kivy\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 26, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
 Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Paulo\PycharmProjects\kivy\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\utils.py", line 496, in __get__
     retval = self.func(inst)
   File "C:\Users\Paulo\PycharmProjects\kivy\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\metrics.py", line 174, in dpi
     EventLoop.ensure_window()
   File "C:\Users\Paulo\PycharmProjects\kivy\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 127, in ensure_window
     sys.exit(1)
 SystemExit: 1
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you installed all  [dependencies](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#installation) correctly? `python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.angle` (Make sure to install in the interpreter / virtual environment that you are using).

Comment: Only angle was updated. The others were ok, but the error is still the same.

Comment: see what happened: C:\Users\Paulo>python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.angle
Requirement already satisfied: docutils
Requirement already satisfied: pygments
Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32 
Requirement already satisfied: kivy.deps.sdl2

Comment: I'm going the reinstall pycharm

Comment: after installing kivy.deps.angle and sdl2 in pycharm the error now is: [CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Also try installing `kivy.deps.glew` in your PyCharm environment.

Comment: After installing kivy.deps.glew in pycharm it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need glew and sdl2 as dependencies. Without one of them, you will probably get one of those errors you are getting. Open command prompt as admin or powershell (any can work) and run the following. I will install glew along with other dependencies. Should take like a minute, and you will be good to go!

*python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew*